# when i am selecting delete option before inserting any value in linked list i am getting segmentation fault error

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

typedef struct nnode
{
    int value;
    struct nnode *next;

} node;

void insert(node **ptr, int val) //for insertion
{
    node *temp, *temp2;
    temp = *ptr;
    if (*ptr == NULL)//if list is empty
  {
        temp = (node *) malloc(sizeof (node));
        temp->value = val;
        temp->next = NULL;
        *ptr = temp;
  }       
        else 
     {
        while (temp->next != NULL)     
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp2 = (node *) malloc(sizeof (node));
        temp2->value = val;
        temp2->next = NULL;
        temp->next = temp2;
     }
}

void display_node(node **ptr)
{
    node *temp;
    temp = *ptr;
    while (temp != NULL) 
   {
    printf("%d--->", temp->value);
    temp = temp->next;
   }
    printf("null");
}

void de_node(node **ptr)
{
    int val;

    node *temp, *temp2;
    temp = *ptr;
    temp2 = temp->next;
    printf("\nenter the value to be deleted\n");
    scanf("%d", &val);
    if ((*ptr) == NULL)
     {
        printf("list is empty .....");
        return;
     } 
    else if ((*ptr)->value == val)
     {

        *ptr = (*ptr)->next;
        free(temp);

     } 
     else 
       {
     while ((temp->next->value != val)&&(temp2->next != NULL))
         {
            temp = temp->next;
            temp2 = temp->next;
         }
        if (temp2->next == NULL)
           {
            printf("\nvalue not found");
           }
        if (temp->next->value == val)             
            {
            temp->next = temp2->next;
            free(temp2);
            }

        }

 }

void main() 
{
    node *head = NULL;
    int ch;
    int n;
    while (1) 
{
        printf("\nenter your choice\n");
        printf("1.ADD ELEMENT\n");
        printf("2.DELETE ELEMENT\n");
        printf("3.DISPLAY LIST\n");
        printf("4.EXIT\n");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 1:printf("\n enter data \n");
                scanf("%d", &n);
                insert(&head, n);
                display_node(&head);
                break;
            case 2:de_node(&head);
                display_node(&head);
                break;
            case 3:display_node(&head);
                break;
            case 4:exit(0);

        }
        }
        }
```

my problem is before inserting anything in list when i am deleting element
    i.e when i am trying to delete an element when list is empty
     then according to my code it should print "list is empty....."
    but instead it is giving segmentation fault error.

Comment: Please format your code. Did you run it in a debugger ? If you don't know how to use a debugger, it's time to start learning it now.

Comment: i think i have formatted the code .can you explain please what is it that you are talking about formatting .actually i am new to programming

Comment: done formatting .now please can someone ans this question please.

Comment: Formatting is better, but still not very good. For example corresponding { and } should be aligned. There is tons of correctly formatted code out there, and the code in your C textbook is (hopefully) also formatted correctly.

Comment: now they are aligned.please solve this problem now .

Comment: and i have debugged the program it stops running at line 54 i.e temp2=temp->next;  and shows segmentation fault.and works perfectly fine when there is an element in the list to delete.

Comment: @AnantBarthwal - OK, given that, did it not occur to you that temp was invalid when the list was empty, maybe NULL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
temp = *ptr;
temp2 = temp->next;
```

You have `temp` set to `*ptr`, but you haven't yet checked if `*ptr` is NULL.  So when you try to dereference it with `temp->next`, you get the segfault.

Since you're not using `temp2` until later, move this line right before your `while` loop:

```
temp2 = temp->next;
```